# give permission to Active directory user to enable/disable a device

Tags: active-directory, permissions, users

In my network, one of users uses DOS application and he need the permission to enable and disable his graphic card using `devcon` command . this user is Active directory user . how can i give him a permission to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

[Technet says](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737393%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> **System Requirements**
>
> The following are the system requirements for this tool:
>
> - Windows 2000 Professional, Windows 2000 Server, Windows XP Professional, or Windows Server 2003
> - To change the properties of device drivers, users must have the following permissions set. Administrators have these permissions.
>
>   - Load\Unload Drivers (set in System Policy Editor, Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User
>       Rights Assignment).
>   - Permission to copy files to the System32\Drivers directory (set in the file system directory).
>   - Permission to write settings to the registry (set in Regedit.exe).
> - To install drivers, users must be logged on to an account in the Administrators group.

In other words:  You're probably going to have to either make him a local administrator.  I can think of two possible alternatives to that:

1. Spend a lot of time trying to find all the files and registry keys you need to grant write access to in order to make it work without administrator privileges. I can't guarantee it'll work, and I kind of feel like granting write access to system32\drivers and the registry is bad enough.
2. Use a third-party tool like [Beyond Trust Powerbroker Desktops](http://www.beyondtrust.com/Products/PowerBrokerforWindows/) and grant privileges to `devcon` itself rather than the user.  (The user would have to be in a special OU to avoid giving *everyone* access to `devcon`.)  I'm not sure if your organization would be willing to deploy that for one user to avoid granting him extra privileges, but if it solves other problems you might be able to sell it to the money folks.

Comment: Or...?  What's the other either?

Comment: Good point.  Edited the answer.